# how to write data to a file

Tags: android, file

in the following lines, i created a file in "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()"

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(dir,"/DCIM/"+fileTitle);
```

my question is: how to write text data to this created file?

Comment: what kind of file do you want to create? text? binary?

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the File using the [FileWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

To output text to file you can use [PrintWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html) class which has different usefull methods for writing data. Also you can take a look at streams [overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html)

Answer (score 0):

From this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html) :

```
//Writing a file...  



try { 
       // catches IOException below
       final String TESTSTRING = new String("Hello Android");

       /* We have to use the openFileOutput()-method
       * the ActivityContext provides, to
       * protect your file from others and
       * This is done for security-reasons.
       * We chose MODE_WORLD_READABLE, because
       *  we have nothing to hide in our file */             
       FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",
                                                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

       // Write the string to the file
       osw.write(TESTSTRING);

       /* ensure that everything is
        * really written out and close */
       osw.flush();
       osw.close();

//Reading the file back...

       /* We have to use the openFileInput()-method
        * the ActivityContext provides.
        * Again for security reasons with
        * openFileInput(...) */

        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("samplefile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);

        /* Prepare a char-Array that will
         * hold the chars we read back in. */
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[TESTSTRING.length()];

        // Fill the Buffer with data from the file
        isr.read(inputBuffer);

        // Transform the chars to a String
        String readString = new String(inputBuffer);

        // Check if we read back the same chars that we had written out
        boolean isTheSame = TESTSTRING.equals(readString);

        Log.i("File Reading stuff", "success = " + isTheSame);

    } catch (IOException ioe) 
      {ioe.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: i tried it out, but when i check if the file is actually created or not, i find that there is no file created

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet that writes data to a file.  Note that it's designed to run in a separate thread, so that you don't do file IO in the main UI thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
  }
}).start();
```